# Class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMSignContext not found

Tags: android, excel, xml, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI library in order to use excel files.

The project was working fine but now I'm getting this error every time I try to build.

Is it related to Apache POI?

Thanks

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMSignContext not found
```

Comment: Having the complete stack-trace one would could see what exact code line throws that exception. So the question whether it is related to `apache poi` would be answered. So why are you not showing the complete stack-trace? Is this kind of a quiz or what?

Comment: @AxelRichter it's a build error

Comment: Each `java.lang.Throwable` provides full stack trace. Sometimes they are obfuscated or shortened by the environment. But as an developer you should be able configuring the environment to show the full stack trace, shouldn't you? Or, if not, you should at least be able logging the full stack trace to a log file.

Comment: javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMSignContext is in the JDK rt.jar (Java 8) - what version of java are you using?

Comment: @PJFanning, I'm using java 8

Comment: I don't develop for android but it wouldn't surprise me if this class was not available in the Android SDK (lots of javax classes are omitted).

Comment: @PJFanning, I found the solution: the issue was due to conflict of multiple dependencies and xml marshaling - unmarshaling. Thanks for your time.